# How to set jwt token expiry time to maximum in nodejs?

Tags: node.js, jwt

I dont want my token to get expire and shold be valid forever.

```
var token = jwt.sign({email_id:'123@gmail.com'}, "Stack", {

                        expiresIn: '24h' // expires in 24 hours

                         });
```

In above code i have given for 24 hours..
I do not want my token to get expire.
What shall be done for this?

Comment: That seems like a bad idea. But you can try to leave this parameter off (check the API documentation for your JWT library). If that does not work, set it to one million hours

Comment: You should add  hours you want to set. Best practice will set to 8760 hours that is 1 year

Comment: so setting hour is mandatory?

Comment: if i give for 10 years by calculating the total number of hours will it work?

Comment: @Jagadeesh check my answer for same

Comment: Are you using this library https://www.npmjs.com/package/jsonwebtoken? Why you do not omit the `expiresIn` param? The `exp` attribute of JWT is optional. You do not need to fill it, and then the token will not expire

Comment: yes i am using the same library...so if i omit it will work right?

Comment: It should work. Try it

Answer (score 87, accepted):

The `exp` claim of a JWT is optional. If a token does not have it, it is considered that it does not expire

According to the documentation of https://www.npmjs.com/package/jsonwebtoken the `expiresIn` field does not have a default value either, so just omit it.

> **There are no default values for expiresIn,** notBefore, audience, subject, issuer. These claims can also be provided in the payload directly with exp, nbf, aud, sub and iss respectively, but you can't include them in both places.

```
var token = jwt.sign({email_id:'123@gmail.com'}, "Stack", {});
```

Answer (score 61):

To set expirey time in days: try this

```
 var token = jwt.sign({email_id:'123@gmail.com'}, "Stack", {

           expiresIn: '365d' // expires in 365 days

      });
```

**"expiresIn" should be a number of seconds or string that repesents a timespan eg: "1d", "20h",**

Docs: [jsonwebtoken](https://www.npmjs.com/package/jsonwebtoken)

Comment: any option for setting up in years?

Comment: I think no. You can set it in days. 365d = 1 year

Comment: if i give for 10 years by calculating the number of days as 3650d will it work?

Answer (score 46):

You can set expire time in number or string :

> expressed in seconds or a string describing a time span
> zeit/ms.
> **Eg: 60, "2 days", "10h", "7d"**.
>
> A numeric value is interpreted as a seconds count. If you use a
> string be sure you provide the time units (days, hours, etc),
> otherwise milliseconds unit is used by default ("120" is equal to
> "120ms").

```
 var token = jwt.sign({email_id:'123@gmail.com'}, "Stack", {
        expiresIn: "10h" // it will be expired after 10 hours
        //expiresIn: "20d" // it will be expired after 20 days
        //expiresIn: 120 // it will be expired after 120ms
        //expiresIn: "120s" // it will be expired after 120s
 });
```

Answer (score 10):

You can save your settings in a config file. 
expires in days use **d** after your desire days like after 90 days should be: **90d**
for hours use **h** for example **20h**

you can use milliseconds also, for example, after 4102444800ms

config.env

```
JWT_SECRET = my-32-character-ultra-secure-and-ultra-long-secret
JWT_EXPIRES_IN = 90d
```

authController.js

```
const signToken = (id) => {
  return jwt.sign({ id: id }, process.env.JWT_SECRET, {
    expiresIn: process.env.JWT_EXPIRES_IN,
  });
};

const signIn = (user) =>{
    const token = signToken(user._id);
}
```

Comment: is expiresIn in jwt different from the maxAge in cookies? I'm sending the jwt as a cookie to the client but it seems like setting expiresIn doesn't affect the cookie

Answer (score 8):

```
  jwt.sign(contentToEncrypt, SECRET_KEY, { expiresIn: '365d' });
```

Answer (score 1):

If you dont set expiresIn options it wont expire.
If you want to set time;

```
('2 days')  // 172800000
('1d')   // 86400000
('10h')  // 36000000
('2.5 hrs') // 9000000
('2h')      // 7200000
('1m')      // 60000
('5s')      // 5000
('1y')      // 31557600000
('100')     // 100
('-3 days') // -259200000
('-1h')     // -3600000
('-200')    // -200
```

Answer (score -1):

```
const expirationTime = Math.floor(Date.now() / 1000) + 15 * 60; // 15 minutes

const token = jwt.sign(
  { userId: user._id },
  process.env.SECRET_KEY,
  { expiresIn: expirationTime },
);
```